# How to do a mininet hard shutdown for switch

Tags: mininet, sdn

With mininet is there a way to make the switch do a hard shutdown (ie power cord pulled) so that the normal graceful switch going down messages are not sent to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Since mininet uses OVS, you have 2 options to achieve your goal. The second one might be exactly what you want:

1. Link down: Modify  characteristics  of port in switch (UP/DOWN). 
   **ovs-ofctl mod-port switch port action**
   See reference here: http://openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-ofctl.8.txt
2. Remove bridge: Deletes  bridge  and  all  of  its  ports.
   **ovs-ofctl del-br bridge**
   See reference here: 
   http://openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-vsctl.8.txt